# gcd between powers of two co-prime numbers

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Is it true that $\forall x,y,n\in \mathbb{Z}$, if $\gcd(x,y)=1$ then $\gcd(x^n, y)=1$? If not, is there a counterexample?

Comment: It's true, and it's a very elementary thing to prove depending on what tools you have. Unless you tell us about what you have available, that's pretty much all that can be said.

Comment: The answer to both questions is "yes".

Comment: @T.Bongers how about only from the definition of gcd?

Comment: Duplicate of [Prove that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $\gcd(a^m, b)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936703/prove-that-if-gcda-b-1-then-gcdam-b-1)

Comment: Also a dupe of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166839/if-gcda-b-1-then-gcdan-bn-1/666339#666339), where there are many other approaches (please don't duplicate these or the  prior-linked answers below).

Answer (score 3):

By Bezout there is $u,v$ so that $xu+yv=1$. Using binomial theorem yields:
$$(xu+yv)^n=x^n{u^n}+ yv\sum_{k=0}^{n- 1}{{n\choose k} (ux)^k(vy)^{n-k-1}}=1$$
Now putting $U’=u^n$ and $V’= v\sum_{k=0}^{n- 1}{{n\choose k} (ux)^k(vy)^{n-k-1}}$ gives: $$U’x^n+V’y=1.$$Hence $\gcd(x^n,y)=1$

Comment: Nice use of binomial expansion.

Comment: @qweruiop In fact the answer is a dupe of an answer in the dupe target I posted above. Please don't duplicate prior answers, esp. if they are already linked on the question.

Comment: @BillDubuque This is not a dupe, since the guy who provide this answer hasn’t make a look into your dupe link.

Comment: @BillDubuque: it is quite possible that this answer was in progress when you posted your link. And my guess is that this question will be closed and deleted soon.

Comment: @robjohn Possibly, but in any case this approach using binomial Bezout (or ideal) expansion (for same or mixed powers) probably occurs in at least 50 prior answers if not more. There is no good reason to further such duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assume $\gcd(x^n,y)\neq 1$. Then there exists a prime $p$ that divides both terms...

Comment: I wonder why there are downvotes on this. I don't really see an issue with this, unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer A guess: the question is a FAQ that has been asked and answered tens (if not hundreds) of times already. Unless one has something *significantly* novel to add then it is best to not further such duplication since it is bad for the health of the site.